# Horizontal UITableViewCell iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to scrolling Horizontal UITableView  in iphone ? or How to create custom Horizontal scrolling UITableViewCell and added with UITableView ? Please  i really need this.Or anyother controls that shows 10 columns per row in UITableView .

My data size is out of the screen for each row i dont want to fold it .So how can i increase the tableview size horizontally ? Is it possible ? I want to show 11 columns per each row in UItableview. Now i can able to create 5 columns per each row.

Thanks in advance.... If possible give some sample code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of questions at once, you should dice them and separate them so that we won't be confused.

Anyhow for the Horizontal Table View, you can subclass UITableViewController

In the viewDidLoad, apply 180 degree rotation.
E.g.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Rotates the view.   
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707963);    
  self.tableView.transform = transform;  
    // Repositions and resizes the view.   
  CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 90, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);  
  self.tableView.frame = contentRect;    
  [super viewDidLoad]; 
}
```

Of course you still need to add some adjustments to the cells inside as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to do it with just an UITableView.

But you can try putting the UITableView in an UIScrollView :-)
Then you would have an horizontal scroll ^^

Good Luck !